# How to compare two date in node js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Compare dates from an array object with the current date. the current date is taken from MongoDB.

```
{"specialData": [
        {
            "content": {
                "dateAdded": "2017-12-26T22:21:37+00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "content": {
                "dateAdded": "2018-01-12T22:21:37+00:00"
            }
        }
]
}
```

compare the content.dateAdded from the array object with the current date coming from MongoDB. current date coming from catalogue.metaData.lastUpdatedDate

```
let result = _.find(rokuFeeds.tvSpecials, function (n) {
      if (new Date(n.content.dateAdded) < new Date(catalogue.metaData.lastUpdatedDate)) {
        return true;
      }
    });
```

I'm trying like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: it's not @CuongVu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare Dates In Mongoose Doc and Express Current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755379/compare-dates-in-mongoose-doc-and-express-current-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare dates by using `getTime()` method.

```js
const obj = {
  "specialData": [{
    "content": {
      "dateAdded": "2017-12-26T22:21:37+00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "content": {
      "dateAdded": "2018-01-12T22:21:37+00:00"
    }
  }]
}

const d1 = new Date(obj.specialData[0].content.dateAdded).getTime();
const d2 = new Date(obj.specialData[1].content.dateAdded).getTime();
```

Now simply compare them, using comparison operators `> < >= <=`

```js
d1 > d2;  //false
d1 < d2;  //true
d1 >= d2; //false
d1 <= d2; //true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date(obj.specialData[0].content.dateAdded);` to convert string to date object.

```js
const obj = {
  "specialData": [{
    "content": {
      "dateAdded": "2017-12-26T22:21:37+00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "content": {
      "dateAdded": "2018-01-12T22:21:37+00:00"
    }
  }]
}
const d1 = new Date(obj.specialData[0].content.dateAdded);
const d2 = new Date(obj.specialData[1].content.dateAdded);

console.log('d1 is:', d1.toLocaleString());
console.log('d2 is:', d2.toLocaleString());

console.log('d1 - d2: ', d1 - d2, 'seconds');
```

#### output

| desc | value |
| --- | --- |
| d1 | 26/12/2017, 23:21:37 |
| d2 | 12/01/2018, 23:21:37 |
| d1 - d2 | -1468800000 *seconds* |